# How to indicate "Our remark"?

Tags: quotations, editing

I have a sentence:

> Before the Greeks, the ancient Egyptians used it (Golden Section - remark is ours) in the construction of their great pyramids.

In that sentence the words "Golden Section" was written by me - not by the author of the sentence.

In which words (remark is ours; note ours or something else?) do I say (designate) that the notes inside a quote are mine?
What are the most common words (phrases) for such cases (except "italics mine," "my
italics," and such; I am not interested in that)?

Comment: can you fix the "quote" it's not clear now what you're trying to ask - okay fixed it - it seems like you're trying to do two different things within one sentence. You might want to break it up.

Answer (score 8):

You could use square brackets

> "Before the Greeks, the ancient Egyptians used it [the Golden Section] in the construction of their great pyramids."

I've also seen quotes like

> "Before the Greeks, the ancient Egyptians used [the Golden Section] in the construction of their great pyramids."

I see this often in newspapers. In academic writing you also see [] as an insertion into a quote that is clearly not a part of the quote. For instance, the use of [sic!] to denote that a quote contains an error, but the error is not made by the one who uses the quote, but by the quote's original author.

> "There was no resemblence [sic!] with the real thing."

Comment: +1 @teylyn thanks for this - need to use [sic] just now! haha

Comment: I wouldn't use an exclamation mark with *sic* unless the error was particularly remarkable.

Comment: The first example is what newspapers or books do. The quare brackets are considered to be editor's remarks.

Answer (score 0):

okay I stepped away and then looked at this again with fresh eyes and now see what you're trying to do - maybe you can try this:

> Before the Greeks, the ancient
>   Egyptians used ***the Golden Section*** in
>   the construction of their great
>   pyramids. ***(emphasis mine)***

Comment: Interesting, but now the original word "it" is gone.

Comment: @drozzy you wouldn't need "it"? :P

Comment: "Emphasis mine" is used when you add underlining, italics, bold, or some other emphasis that was not in the original. You do not use "emphasis mine" when you add your own words, as the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

How about,:

Before the Greeks, the ancient Egyptians used the Golden Section in the construction of their great pyramids.(Term of Author's origin--Golden Section)